# String being misinterpreted or the issue is more intricate

Tags: c#, command-line, system.diagnostics, string-literals

I have a small program which runs a Command line through cmd.exe, purely for comfort.

It's basically designed to give me the option in a single program to wake up another PC (or directly connect to it using TightVNC to put it in stand-by mode).

The issue I'm having is as follows:

This piece of code here:

```
string strCmdText = @"cd /D C:\ && cd Program Files\TightVNC && _
 tvnviewer.exe 192.168.0.233 -password=******";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText);
```

For some reason this code isn't working for me. It's not giving me any output in the command terminal, nor does it open the TightVNC process, while when I simply copy/paste this into my command line, it works just fine, instantly opening the connection.

I thought: "Maybe it's the eventual output for the `strCmdText` variable having double backslashes, but as the same method worked before in this code:

```
string path = @"C:\Users\Yorrick\Desktop\wakemeonlan\WakeMeOnLan.exe";
string commandText = path + @" /wakeup 192.168.0.233";
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = commandText;
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
```

There, the `commandText` variable has the double backslashes aswell (`\\`).

Anyone that could help me find a solution for this? It's not that I REALLY need this program, but I'd like having it as it'd save me a bit of time (I like having my Desktop clutter-free, thus I try to use as few shortcuts on there as I possibly can)

Thanks, Yorrick

EDIT: Appearantly adding the "/C" to the start of my command, it does work.

(`string strCmdText = @"/C cd /D C:\ && cd Program Files\TightVNC && _
     tvnviewer.exe 192.168.0.233 -password=******";`)

I thought the usage of /C was simply for closing the command terminal after the command was executed & didn't have anything to do with the command actually being executed or not?

Anyone who can clarify why this suddenly works?

Comment: It may have to do with your command concatenation. Without the /C switch, that might not work. Try a sinle command first. Oh, and better yet, Use a `ProcessStartInfo` instead of cd'ing to the target folder. Then you dont even need cmd.exe, but you can launch the viewer directly.

Comment: I tried using a single command the before concatenating the commands like this, it gave me the exact same result without using the /C switch. Yes, I probably should have thought of that option before, but I'm getting pretty tired, and since this isn't a commercial product, I don't really mind if I do something a bit sloppy, all I expect is a good result :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your edit, the `/C` flag does not mean close — it means execute the following command. So not including the `/C` flag will not run your command.